# div tag is not visible on integration with Menubar in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, highcharts

I have made a chart by using high chart jquery library .My charts are visible fine when it is   only in jsp page but as soon as i try to integrate it with my menu bar page it is giving not displaying the chart.I am not getting where i am wrong ...

I tried to see the error in Firebug and every thing is fine as data is coming from server side code..

Here is my head content of jsp page..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var dbdata="";
    var fancy_array = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getPieChartcallcountbysite',
            async:false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
                var i;  
                for(i = 0; i < dbdata.length;i=i+2)
                {
                    var item = [dbdata[i], dbdata[i+1]];
                    fancy_array.push(item);
                }
                console.log(fancy_array);       
            }      
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Graphical Analysis of CallBilling, 2013'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: "CallCount {point.y:.0f}"
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Call Type',
                    data:fancy_array

                }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false }
        });
    });

</script>
```

and here is my body content ...

```
 <div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">

        <li><a href="Home.aspx" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Reports</span></a>
            <div><ul>

                    <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Details</span></a>
                        <div><ul>
                                <li><a href="daterange.jsp" >Generic Detail Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Extension.jsp">ExtensionWise Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Trunk.jsp">TrunkWise Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Department.jsp">DepartmentWise Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="WWIDwise.jsp">WWIDwise Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="site.jsp">Sitewise Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ServiceProvider.jsp">ServiceProviderwise Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="TOPNUSER.jsp">Top N User Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="DetailCountry.jsp">Countrywise Report</a></li>
                            </ul></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<br/>
<div id="container" style="width:550px; height: 200px; margin:0 auto"></div>
```

Please help me to find out the problem..I am totally struck in the situation..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

if it works only without the `<div id="menu"> ... </div>` block i think there is a conflict by ids and the way is to change the #menu to something more unique.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize chart inside AJAX, in separate $(function)... Morever $(function is the same as $(document).ready(). As a result please check if this will work:

```
    var dbdata="";
    var fancy_array = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getPieChartcallcountbysite',
            async:false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
                var i;  
                for(i = 0; i < dbdata.length;i=i+2)
                {
                    var item = [dbdata[i], dbdata[i+1]];
                    fancy_array.push(item);
                }
                console.log(fancy_array);   
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Graphical Analysis of CallBilling, 2013'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: "CallCount {point.y:.0f}"
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Call Type',
                    data:fancy_array

                }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false }
        });    
            }      
        });
    });
```